# Calling a view from the second project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects in the Solution (asp.net-mvc). The first project is main, the other project (1 simple controller and views (Index, Layout). I want directly from the menu in the project 1, to refer to the Index view of the second project. I added a reference but I do not know what to do. Someone help?

Ps: Sorry for my english.

Project 1

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="@Url.Content("~")" id="current">Home</a>
            <a href="@Url.Content( /*
                via a link you want to get to the index from Project 2
            */)">TEST</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Project 2

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace Panel.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your gonna have to show some code. What have you tried?

Comment: I added the code. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I want to turn on the second project by clicking the link in the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC default provider does not support cross reference views. However, there are few hacks I found out when I was working in a MVC-4 app, mostly what they do is customizing the `VirtualPathProvider`. David Ebbo wrote [Razor Generator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/).

You can find a test/sample application in [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/MvcApplicationRazorGeneratorSeparateLibrary). A detail [blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/). Also look for `PortableArea` in google.

Though don't know when they had been last updated but these are your possible choices for now I think.